# Need help regarding Binary Powering with a matrix

Tags: python, matrix, binary

I am trying to write a program that can calculate the nth power of 2x2 matrix using binary powering. I would really appreciate the help. My problem is that the code is only working for a matrix to the power of 2.

```
   def binPow(m,n):
    if (n==0): return[[1,0],[0,1]]
    q = binPow(m,n//2)
    square = MatrMult(o,o)
    if (n%2==0):
        return square
    else:
        return MatrMult(m,square)

def MatrMult(o,x):
    o = [[b,c],[e,f]]
    g = [[(b*b)+(c*e),(b*c)+(c*f)],[(e*b)+(f*e),(e*c)+(f*f)]]
    return(g)

b = int(input("Enter A1: ")) 
c = int(input("Enter A2: "))
e = int(input("Enter A3: "))
f = int(input("Enter A4: "))
o = [[b,c],[e,f]]
n = int(input("Enter Power: "))

print(o, "to the power of", n, " is ", binPow(o,n))
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with the third line q=binPow(m, n/2) it returns this error "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison"

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 3.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python3, `n/2` will result in a floating point number.  `1/2` is `0.5`, `0.5/2` is `0.25`, `0.25/2` is `0.125`, etc.  It never gets to 0, so `if (n==0): ...` will never execute.  To make sure that `n` is always a whole number, double your slashes: `q = binPow(m, n//2)`.  That way, `5//2` becomes `2` instead of `2.5`, etc.  Your real problem is how you are multiplying the matrices.  You are always squaring the original matrix because you don't do anything with the parameters given you.  I also took the liberty of modifying your `binPow()` function to something a little simpler:

```
def binPow(m,n):
    if (n==0): return[[1,0],[0,1]]
    q = m 
    while n > 1:
        q = MatrMult(m, q)
        n -= 1
    return q

def MatrMult(o,x):
    ((a, b), (c, d)) = o 
    ((e, f), (g, h)) = x 
    g = [[(a*e)+(b*g),(a*f)+(b*h)],[(c*e)+(d*g),(c*f)+(d*h)]]
    return(g)
```

Comment: Thank you! I am still having trouble with the program only working for a matrix to the power o 2

Comment: I'm working on it.  I know your problem, but I'm working on how to fix it.

Comment: @KateWylie: Okay.  I edited my answer.  Does that make up for my referring to you as "he"? :D

Comment: Thanks!! Hahaha all is forgiven. XD